# Mongo using indexes with sort

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to optimize a mongodb query.  I have an index on `from_account_id`, `to_account_id`, and `created_at`.  But the following query does a full collection scan.

```
{
    "ts": {
        "$date": "2012-03-18T20:29:27.038Z"
    },
    "op": "query",
    "ns": "heroku_app2281692.transactions",
    "query": {
        "$query": {
            "$or": [
                {
                    "from_account_id": {
                        "$oid": "4f55968921fcaf0001000005"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "to_account_id": {
                        "$oid": "4f55968921fcaf0001000005"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "$orderby": {
            "created_at": -1
        }
    },
    "ntoreturn": 25,
    "nscanned": 2643718,
    "responseLength": 20,
    "millis": 10499,
    "client": "10.64.141.77",
    "user": "heroku_app2281692"
}
```

If I don't do the `or`, and only query `from_account_id` or `to_account_id` with an order on it, it's fast.

What's the best way to get the desired effect?  Should I be keeping account_ids (both from and to) in one field like an array?  Or perhaps there is a better way.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, as you have discovered, an $or clause can make life difficult for the optimizer.

So, to work around this you have a couple options. Among them:

- Divide your query into two and manually merge the results.
- Change your data model to allow efficient querying. For example, you might add a "referenced_accounts" field that is an array of all the accounts referenced in the transaction.

Comment: $or in Mongo doesn't make optimizer skip indexes. It does skip indexes for nested $or statements:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel#issue-tabs

Comment: Btw, in case anyone was curious, I made a new Array field called `referenced_accounts` which auto updates using an `after_update` filter in rails.  This single field can now be queried with an index.  A little bit of duplication but it works well.